# rails3 routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been working with **rails3**, here the view.html.erb form have one login button, so when i click on that button, gives no routes matches :controller => 'home', :action => 'login'. But i have put that in routes.rb. Why this happening?

**view.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag( { :controller => 'home', :action => 'login' }, { :method
  => 'post'}) do %>
  <%= text_field(:name, :name, :class => "span2",:placeholder => 
  "Username") %>
  <%= password_field_tag(:password, :password,  :class =>"span2") %>
  <%= submit_tag "Login", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

**routes.rb**

resources :home
resources :home do
  post :login, :on => :member   
end

**homecontroller.rb**

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def login

  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined "resources :home" twice, first declaration is useless and overrides second.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used resources to define your routes (which is recomended) you should use the helper method generated, in this case its `login_home_path` instead of the old syntax `{ :controller => 'home', :action => 'login' }`

Answer (score 0):

First,

- You declare resources :home two times.

try this way in your routes.rb

```
 resources :home
 match '/login',  to: 'home#login'
```

and use login_path in submit tag.

I would prefere for login, logout, create Sessions controller

```
rails generate controller Sessions --no-test-framework
```

and for login create `new` method and for logout(signout) create `destroy` method